# process.env returns undefined when using .env.development instead of .env

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am using Webpack for development.

When I run the project using `.env` file, it works as expected.

But when I change it filename to `.env.development`, the `process.env` become `undefined`.

How can I fix it?

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js"
```

webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const Dotenv = require("dotenv-webpack");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/index.jsx"),
  devtool: "source-map",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "/dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    static: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    open: true,
  },
  resolve: {...},
  module: {...},
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "public/index.html",
      filename: "index.html",
      favicon: "public/favicon.ico",
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: "process/browser",
    }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: You didn't change any of the configuration to reflect the change in filename. `dotenv` looks for `.env`, hence the name; if you want it to look for something else you need to _tell it that_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so how to tell it that?

Comment: Well given that you're using `dotenv-webpack`, did you read https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack to find out what config it exposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dotenv` by default only looks for a `.env` file. This is deliberate, as an env file should be local only and specific for the environment the app is running in. You shouldn't be keeping around different versions of the env for different environments.

I'll quote from `dotenv`'s docs:

> [**Should I have multiple .env files?**](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#should-i-have-multiple-env-files)
>
> No. We **strongly** recommend against having a "main" `.env` file and an
> "environment" `.env` file like `.env.test`. Your config should vary
> between deploys, and you should not be sharing values between
> environments.
>
> > In a twelve-factor app, env vars are granular controls, each fully orthogonal to other env vars. They are never grouped together as
> > “environments”, but instead are independently managed for each deploy.
> > This is a model that scales up smoothly as the app naturally expands
> > into more deploys over its lifetime.
> >
> > – [The Twelve-Factor App](http://12factor.net/config)

You *can* however, tell `dotenv-webpack` where to look for your file if you choose:

```
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv({
        path: './.env.development',
    }),
```